# How to pass dynamic arguments in Postman scripts collections

Tags: javascript, rest, api, collections, postman

I would like to pass dynamic argument as part of Request URL

Like

Few of the elements from Response body of First API should be input or should go as input as part of Request URL in second REST API

Ex :
Below is the Response body of First API

```
{
    "locations": [
        {
            "locationID": 1,

            "locationDescription": null
        },
        {
            "locationID": 2,

            "locationDescription": null
        },
        {
            "locationID": 3,

            "locationDescription": null
        }
    ],`enter code here`
    "locationCount": 3
}
```

In this i need to select only value of location id and i would like to save that in JSON object and i would like to pass those location id as  part of Request URL in second API

Second API request URL :

```
hostname/cpi/locations/{{locationID}}
```

I would like to use  setNextRequest method and would like to call second API number of times depending on number of location ids id get as response of first API

Below is the rough code i am using but it is not working please help

```
 for(i = 1; i<pm.globals.get("indexOfLocationId");i++)
   {   
      pm.globals.set("locationID", i)
      postman.setNextRequest('Second REST API Name')
      console.log(responseBody);
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't think that the `setNextRequest()` function would work in that way as it's used in a workflow rather than in a loop. It doesn't matter where you have it in your code it'll be the last thing to run. Check out the documentation. Could you used the `sendRequest()` function instead?

Comment: Thanks for response for Danny

Comment: But SendRequest function doesn't exist with postman scripts and i am able to call API using setNextRequest() properly but arguments present in part of request URL hostname/cpi/locations/{{locationID}} is not dynamically getting changed